# React navigation to control content in panel below

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and looking for some best practices. I'm making a Chrome extension that's a small widget. The widget has 3 sections. Call `Section A`, `Section B`, and `Section C`. At the top of the widget I want to have buttons like so:

```
[logo]                                  | Section A | Section B | Section C |

[


      Panel Content (Default Section A)



 ]
```

And when one of those section links are clicked, the content in the panel below updates with the relevant content for that section.

My first thought was to render all of them, and then just hide `jQuery show/hide()` on the panels. It works, but I'd rather not do that because each panel loads some data asynchronously and I'd rather not pay that price up front if the user never clicks on the latter 2 links.

I've created React components for each section so their easy to swap out.

I then tried this:

```
  showSectionB: function(){
    React.renderComponent(
      <SectionBList person={this.props.person} />,
      document.querySelector('.main .panel')
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="T-I-ax7" onClick={this.showSectionB}>Section B</button>
        </div>
        <div className="panel">
          <SectionAList person={this.props.person} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It felt more logical, but feels weird I'm reaching inside a component for the container to place the component. On top of that, the whole browser locked up and gave me this message after the panel switched:

```
React attempted to use reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server.
```

Is there a better way to hand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to React is to always go through `render()` to render your application. User interaction should only fire events that trigger a re-`render()`. In your example `onClick` should call `setState()` to do that.

```
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      section: "a"
    };
  },

  showSectionB: function(){
    // Update the component's state for a re-render().
    this.setState({ 
      section: "b"
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.section == "a") {
      var section = <SectionAList person={ this.props.person } />;
    } 
    else if (this.state.section == "b") {
      var section = <SectionBList person={ this.props.person } />;
    }
    return (  
      <div className="main">
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="T-I-ax7" onClick={ this.showSectionB }>Section B</button>
        </div>
        <div className="panel">
          { section }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Updated** thanks for the comment!

Comment: Storing components in state is an antipattern that the React docs outline in ["What shouldn't go in state?"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state). You could base its rendering off of a boolean named "isSectionBShown" or something similar, store only the boolean in `this.state`.

Comment: The revisions look great.

Comment: Nice. This makes total sense. Thanks for the insight!